# java and xml not linking together properly

Tags: android

In my program when I create a second java page it also creates a second xml page like it's supposed to. yet it seems that the two are not linking together properly. the second java page seems to be linked to the first xml instead of the second xml and I'm unsure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

open your second .xml file and find this

- 1:

> tools:context="com.example.projName.MainActivity

now write your java file name instead of ( MainActivity ) 
then it will link your java java file with your second xml file

- 2:

> setContentView(R.layout.Your_XML_FileName);

check in java file in setContentView does it have your second cml if not then edit it and write your xml file name

Comment: that line isn't even there in the first place, when i add that in and change it to the java file name the entire thing gets underlined in read and says "unexpected token"

Comment: whoops, i was looking in the wrong place for one of the things. both of them are present yet its still not working properly.